# Cannot run carrot2 workbench 3.10.2 in Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, carrot2

I have Java 1.7.0...

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_75"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_75-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
```

And Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, running KDE (Kubuntu). When I run `./carrot2-workbench-ubuntu` I get...

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: You have loaded library /var/downloads/a/packages/carrot2-workbench-3.10.2/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326/eclipse_1605.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
2015-08-03 20:01:08,984 INFO  org.carrot2.workbench.core.WorkbenchCorePlugin: Changed instanceLocation to: file:/var/downloads/a/packages/carrot2-workbench-3.10.2/workspace/
2015-08-03 20:01:09,223 INFO  org.carrot2.util.xslt.TemplatesPool: XSLT transformer factory: com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl
```

After that I get a pop-up window that says the following:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java
-Xms256m
-Xmx512m
-Dorg.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-workbench.xml
-jar /var/downloads/a/packages/carrot2-workbench-3.10.2/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /var/downloads/a/packages/carrot2-workbench-3.10.2/carrot2-workbench
-name Carrot2-workbench
--launcher.library /var/downloads/a/packages/carrot2-workbench-3.10.2/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326/eclipse_1605.so
-startup /var/downloads/a/packages/carrot2-workbench-3.10.2/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 1af001e
-data @noDefault
-vm /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms256m
-Xmx512m
-Dorg.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-workbench.xml
-jar /var/downloads/a/packages/carrot2-workbench-3.10.2/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
```

Can someone please help me decipher what's wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting the issue (although the mailing list would be more convenient). I'll look into this.

http://issues.carrot2.org/browse/CARROT-1108

Comment: I will next time, sorry about that. :-)

Comment: Check out my comments on the bug report above. I've succeeded at running C2 Workbench on Kubuntu, although with some hacks.

Comment: Workaround works great, thank you very much. No problems with stability so far.